# How to know if a page is blank or parked domain in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to find out the `httpstatus` of a bunch of urls via ruby `Net::Http`, but the problem is even the blank pages as well as the parked domains return a status of `200 OK`. Is there anyway I can weed out these type of urls?

Comment: How would you - as a person - differentiate between a parked domain and a simple one-page website that is in use?

Comment: Automatically? Not without examining page content and guessing.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify few points:

1. HTTP Status will not help to identify if a domain is or not parked. They exist to tell if everything went ok or not.
2. To track down parked domains, you will need to develop your own approach as a park domain page is just an HTML page...

Few things you can try:

- Look for css, js or even text in the page with the "park domain" mention. Some keywords you may want to look for: *domain available / parked / renewable / etc.*
- test couple of different prefixes for a given domain (domain.com, asds.domain.com, fgffg.domain.com). If they redirect to the same page, it's likely to be a parked domain
- Identify the structure of parked domain pages for the main registrars. All site having a landing page matching this structure will be parked domains
- Build a list of DNS used for parked domains. If the domain is managed by one of the DNS in your list, then it is parked.
- Use a list of parked domain providers ([see for some examples](https://www.namepros.com/threads/list-of-domain-parking-sites.304747/), some links may be broken)

sources:

[Method to detect a parked page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490025/method-to-detect-a-parked-page)

[Some key phrased for parked domains by Gary Sieling](https://www.garysieling.com/blog/detecting-parked-domains)